# SuiteCRM API full authentication and login

Tags: php, rest, api, suitecrm

Is there a away to gain full access to SuiteCRM through background API login?

For example, we use LDAP on a separate site and I want to pass authenticated users to suitecrm in the background then have suitecrm grant access to said user without them having to log in for a second time.

I have been able to get the API to work and 'login' a user and return a session_id, however it still directs me to the login page. If I attempt to force a redirect I get an err_to_many_redirects.

EDIT:

I do not believe the issue arises from the API script but using the returned data to complete the session data required, which I have yet been able to generate.

Code below acquired from http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Logging_In/

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

require_once('./shield_secureaccess.php');

$url = "http://{site_location}/service/v4_1/rest.php";
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['SHIELD_user'];
session_write_close();
if(isset($username)){
        $password = shield_secureaccess($username);}
else{require 'shield_session.php';}

        //function to make cURL request
    function call($method, $parameters, $url)
    {
        ob_start();
        $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);
        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);

        $response = json_decode($result[1]);
        ob_end_flush();

        return $response;
    }

    //login ------------------------------
    $login_parameters = array(
         "user_auth" => array(
              "user_name" => $username,
              "password" => md5($password),
              "version" => "1"
         ),
         "application_name" => "RestTest",
         "name_value_list" => array(),
    );

    $login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);



    echo "<pre>";
//      print_r($_SESSION);
    print_r($login_result);
//      print_r($current_user);

print_r($_SESSION);

    echo "</pre>";
    //get session id
    $session_id = $login_result->id;



//      header("Location: http://{site_location}/index.php?module=Home&action=inde");
//      header("Location: http://{site_location}/index.php?MSID=$session_id");
?>
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: added, however the API doesn't appear to be the issue it's what to do with it after

Comment: so you are logging in from API and then redirect user to suitecrm ?

Comment: Basically. The hard authentication is done from another main site, and I am passing an authorized user into suitecrm. My goal is to bypass the login screen and give an impression of an SSO, easiest way to do this I found is generate an API call in the background to log the user into suitecrm and go directly to their home page. The login appears to be successful however the redirect fails and there is no $_SESSION data generated on the login, even though it generates an MSID.

Comment: for SSO type functionality, this will not work. API login only work for API not for SuiteCRM.

Comment: Well, nuts. I suppose now my only option is to rewrite the authentication mech which I was trying to avoid. I appreciate the help Star

Comment: Yes you are right. to make it easier, here is hint: look into "modules/Users/Authenticate.php" which is being used by SuiteCRM for user validation and then logging-in a user into app.

Comment: moreover it will be good if you post your code after completion of this task. This will help other for similar thing.

Comment: I can do that, though the original question will be misleading as since API wont work it will be custom authentication file. Initially looking at this, it appears it will be easier than I thought which is typical of always trying the hardest thing first ha. Appreciate it Star

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The session id can't be used straight away to login, you first must call `seamless_login`.

So the flow is:

1. Do API login as above.
2. Call seamless_login this will return 0 or 1
3. Navigate the user to `http://{site_location}/index.php?MSID=$session_id` where `$session_id` is the session id from the original API login call.