# suitecrm err_too_many_redirects on login

Tags: php, suitecrm

This is second attempt to login in a user in the background and bypassing the login page. First attempt [SuiteCRM API full authentication and login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176429/suitecrm-api-full-authentication-and-login) which was an incorrect path forward. However I get the same error I received there.

I have created a custom Authentication.php file and called it from index.php with the condition !isset($current_user). Relevant code follows:

at end of index.php: require_once('./portal.php);

portal.php:

```
<?php

if(!isset($current_user)){
        require_once('./custom/modules/Users/Authenticate.php');}

require_once('./modules/UserPreferences/UserPreference.php');
$current_user->loadPreferences();

//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($_SESSION);
//echo '</pre>';die;

$url = 'Location: index.php?module=Home&action=index';
header($url);

?>
```

Within {core_site}/custom/modules/Users/Authenticatate.php:

```
require_once(core_site.'/modules/Users/authentication/AuthenticationController.php');



if (!defined('SUITE_PHPUNIT_RUNNER')) {
    session_regenerate_id(false);
}
global $mod_strings;
$login_vars = $GLOBALS['app']->getLoginVars(false);

//$user_name = isset($_REQUEST['user_name'])
//    ? $_REQUEST['user_name'] : '';

//$password = isset($_REQUEST['user_password'])
//    ? $_REQUEST['user_password'] : '';

require_once('shield_secureaccess.php');
$user_name= isset($_SESSION['SHIELD_user']) ? $_SESSION['SHIELD_user'] : '';
if(isset($user_name)){$password = shield_secureaccess($user_name);}
```

I am able to login and successfully authenticate the user, however it appears only half of the $_SESSION data is generated as compared to a standard login. Because of this I believe that I am getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I attempt to redirect to Location: index.php?module=Home&action=index..

Anyone have any thoughts on what I am missing?

EDIT:

calling $app->execute after the login sequence it logs in. However now I get content errors on a few of the modules. Oddly enough though not all of them. So Now I am more lost than before

FINAL EDIT:

Fixed everything and works perfectly. Turns out some stray echo's and error_displays from debugging the php code was breaking the AJAX calls on certain modules. Once removed everything works perfectly.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT.    call  $app->execute() after all login calls and everything EDIT does not work out perfectly but I am part of the way there.

Comment: can you post complete code with all the details for other Devs here...